# Magento2 Transform Multi Select Attribute Filter into Swatch Filter

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

is there a way in Magento 2 to transform a product multi select attribute, which is used as a filter into a color swatch on frontend?

We need this attribute in backend as multi select but have to transform it in frontend to a color swatch  (as keys we have add the hex values of the color ).

Any ideas?